# How to print formatted float in obj-c with number of digits from parameter

Tags: objective-c

I know the way to set formatted float with specific number

```
NSLog(@"%.2f", myFloat);
```

What is the way to set parameter number? Something like this

```
cell.lblOpenPrice.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.%if", trade.open_price, trade.digits];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an instance of [`NSNumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnumberformatter?language=objc) for this. There are dozens of options, too many to discuss them here. I. e. you can set the total number of digits (significant digits) or the number of integer and fraction digits as discussed [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnumberformatter?language=objc#overview).

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
// Do the desired configuration
NSString *text = [formatter stringFromNumber:@(myFloat)];
```

Comment: Thank you! 
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
    [formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:trade.digits];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:trade.digits];
    [formatter setMinimumIntegerDigits:1];

Answer (score 0):

To set a field precision dynamically you use an asterisk in the format and provide the precision argument first, so your code example is:

```
cell.lblOpenPrice.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.*f", trade.digits, trade.open_price];
```

HTH